# Is it possible to pass some events down and others not in NotebookEventActions?

Tags: notebooks

Executing the code below yields a dropdown menu of possible words as you type them in a text cell.

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, NotebookEventActions -> {
   
   "KeyDown" :> {FrontEndTokenExecute["CompleteSelection"]},
   
   {"KeyDown", "\t"} :> {(*Do Nothing*)}
   
   , PassEventsDown -> True}]
```

My problem is the second event.  I don't want the tab key event to be passed down.  However, I need all other keydown events to be passed down.  Is this possible?